# How to abort ajax with promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, abort

I'm using something like the function below to send multiple ajax requests to break up a long running process. I want to add a cancel button to abort all ajax. I've tried pooling all the requests into an array like this and then iterating through and aborting them...

I've tried many variations of this to abort all ajax requests.

```
$.xhrPool = [];

$.xhrPool.abortAll = function() {
    $.each(this, function(jqXHR) { 
        jqXHR.abort(); 
    });
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

//gives me... Uncaught TypeError: $.xhrPool.abortAll is not a function
```

But it's not working. Is there a solution for this?

This is similar to the ajax request chain with promises.

```
function processBigArray(bigArray, chunkSize) {
    // pre-split array into chunks
    var chunkArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i += chunkSize) {
        chunkArray.push(bigArray.slice(bigArray, i, chunkSize));
    }

    var results = [];

    // use .reduce() design pattern for chaining and serializing
    // a sequence of async operations
    return chunkArray.reduce(function (p, chunk) {
        return p.then(function () {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'process_big_array',
                    'array_to_process': chunk
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    xxx
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            }).then(function (data) {
                results.push(data);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function () {
        // depending upon what your ajax returns, results might be an array of arrays
        // that you would want to flatten
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the code which tries to cancel the running ones?

Comment: The logic you have pooling all the requests is the correct way to do this. How are you attempting to abort the in-progress requests contained in that array?

Comment: I just added more above. I've tried different versions of that.

Comment: Also, I would normally declare variables like "var xhrPool = [];". I'm not familiar with "$.xhrPool = [];" but I was seeing it all over the place. Is that the correct syntax? I've tried it both ways.